# Calculate Discount amount Based on Quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
SELECT PRD_CODE,PRD_MAKE,PRD_NAME FROM PRD_MST
SELECT PDI_DISC_QTY,PDI_DISC_PRICE FROM PRD_DISC_INF
select customerid,Productid,quantity from ShoppingCartItem
```

**Records**

**PRD_MST**

```
    PRD_CODE    PRD_MAKE         PRD_NAME
    ----------- ---------------- ----------
    4           mobile           moto e
    5           cycle            hero
```

**PRD_DISC_INF**

```
    PDI_DISC_QTY      PDI_DISC_PRICE
    ----------------- ------------------
    2.00              2.10
    1.00              2.31
```

**ShoppingCartItem**

```
    customerid  Productid   quantity
    ----------- ----------- -----------
    1           5           5
```

The Problem is that
if a customer buy 5 mobile and price of single unit is 200 then how do i calculate discount amount base on `PDI_DISC_QTY` in table 'PRD_DISC_INF'

Need help i am unable to get the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2daf/14)

```
select PDI_DISC_QTY *
   (cast(round(((select quantity from ShoppingCartItem)/PDI_DISC_QTY),0) as int))
from PRD_DISC_INF ;
```